# get runtime of a program from shell

Tags: shell, runtime

I have the following script named timed which I got from [here](http://klassenresearch.orbs.com/Timing+a+program+from+the+shell).

```
    #!/bin/sh
    START=$(date +%s)
    STARTnano=$(date +%N)

    $@  # Command-line arguments, i.e. the program you wish to time

    END=$(date +%s)
    ENDnano=$(date +%N)

    DIFF=$(( (10#$END - 10#$START) * 1000000000 ))
    DIFFnano=$(( (10#$ENDnano - 10#$STARTnano)  ))

    DIFF=$(( 10#$DIFF + 10#$DIFFnano ))

    DIFFu=$(( 10#$DIFF / 1000000000 )) # Get correct units
    DIFFd=$(( 10#$DIFF - 10#$DIFFu ))  # Get figures after decimal place

    echo "'$@' took ${DIFFu}.${DIFFd} seconds to finish."
```

I'm trying to use it to measure the runtime of a program.

It doesn't work. I keep getting an error that it lacks a ')'. Can someone point out what's going wrong?

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: Are all the # (comment) markers supposed to be there? e.g. `10#$END` look like a dodgey commenting job...

Comment: That's not comments, it means that the number should be interpreted as base 10.

Comment: You should use `"$@"` to execute the command; that will preserve spaces in arguments, etc.

Comment: Given the error, I suspect that @John3136's comment is reasonably accurate, coupled with the use of `/bin/sh` in the shebang.  What happens if you run your script using `bash yourscript.sh ls -l`?  What happens if you run your script using `sh yourscript.sh ls -l`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the execution time of a script it will be precise if you use time command.

for example

```
$time ls

**output of ls**

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
```

There is meaning for what is meant by real, user and sys. Use 'man time' for more information.
you can substitute ls with any command(or script)